# Deriving 3 unknown variables from a function

Tags: excel, math, statistics

I have a excel datasheet that has 4 columns. Every column is a number and the first one is dependant on the other three with a function that looks like this

```
first = (a*second) + (b*third) + (c*fourth)
```

In theory I would only need 3 sets of the (first, second, third, fourth), but I have >100 of them. The variables a, b and c will not be perfectly defined, but I would be happy with some sort of an aproximation.

Is there some way I can do this in excel or can you maybe suggest some different mathematical tool to find the best aproximation of these variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sets of the (first, second, third, fourth) so I suppose you need to calculate (a, b, c).

You can do this using the `LINEST` function.

Example:

[image]

Formulas:

In `G3:I3`

`{=LINEST(A3:A8,C3:E8,FALSE)}`

This is an array formula. Input it in `G3` without the curly brackets, then select `G3:I3`, click in the Formula bar and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter].

In `K3` downwards

`=C3*$I$3+D3*$H$3+E3*$G$3`